# Find number of records present in the mysql database

Tags: mysql, records

How to find number of records present in a particular database? 
For example I have 3 databases namely **a,b,c** and now I want to count total number of records present in **a** database.

Answer (score 2):

you could extract this from the information_schema:

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA ='a';
```

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM has an accurate row count because it always locks the table when write operations are done - which means it can keep accurate track of the number of rows (every MyISAM table has a row counter).

InnoDB cannot do what MyISAM does because it allows row-level locking which means some rows may be deleted and no central accurate counter is kept. The `information_schema` counter is an estimate of the number of rows in the table.

The only way to accurately count InnoDB rows in a table is to use `COUNT(*)` on that table which needs to do a full table scan.

You can do:

```
SELECT SUM(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_innodb_table
        UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_other_innodb_table
        UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_yet_another_innodb_table
);
```

Answer (score 0):

all database information stored on information_schema database. So you can explore this database.

```
use information_schema;
select sum(table_rows) from tables where table_schema = 'db_name';
```